# Directory must contain only one JAR file

Tags: sonarqube

After installing sonarqube on a ubuntu machine I started it with the console parameter and got the error message:

```
WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: org.sonar.process.MessageException: Directory must contain only one JAR file: lib/jdbc/mysql
```

I'm using a mySQL database, it's actually looking for the right driver, but in the mentioned directory (lib/jdbc/mysql) is just one jar file.
Any suggestion, what the system is complaining about ?

Comment: Have you made any modification to the wrapper.conf file? What version of SonarQube are your using? Please edit your question to add all those missing details so that we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error. Turned out there was another .jar in each of the database directories, with the same name as the main .jar, but they were hidden. For instance, the contents of the directory would be as follows:

- name_of_database.jar
- ._name_of_database.jar

Remove the latter and try starting the server again.

Answer (score 0):

For me:

```
$ ls lib/jdbc/postgresql/
postgresql-9.4.1209.jre7.jar            postgresql-9.4.1212.jar
postgresql-9.4.1209.jre7.sonar_bad_jar
```

Deleting postgresql-9.4.1209.jre7.jar and postgresql-9.4.1209.jre7.sonar_bad_jar fixed the problem.